# What's the difference between "blond" and "blonde"?

Tags: differences, grammatical-gender

I hear all the time that one word is for males and the other is for females but I'm skeptical...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The usage note under **blond** in the NOAD entry is explicit:

> The spellings **blonde** and **blond** correspond to the feminine and masculine forms in French. Although the distinction is usually retained in Britain, American usage since the 1970s has generally preferred the gender-neutral **blond**. The adjective **blonde** may still refer to a woman’s (but not a man’s) hair color, though use of the noun risks offense ( : *See that blonde over there?*): the offense arises from the fact that the color of hair is not the person. The adjective applied to inanimate objects (wood, beer) is typically spelled **blond**.

Comment: Well, since I am British, I should retain the male/female divide, yes?

Comment: Apparently so. But it does say the distinction is usually retained, not absolutely, so you may have some flexibility, although probably it's best to err on the side of most common usage.

Comment: No. Since you're British you may be forgiven for retaining the distinction *if you're already in the habit of so doing*. But if you have no pre-existing proclivity, stick to **blond** to avoid looking archaic (in the foreseeable future, if not already).

Comment: Hmmm, the part about American usage being gender-neutral "blond" doesn't match up with my experience as an American.  :-)  My experience is that the male/female distinction is normally observed.  In the cases when it's not, "blonde" is what's used, NOT "blond"...  I frequently see "blonde" used when "blond" would be the correct choice, but can't recall ever seeing "blond" used instead of "blonde"...

Comment: As an American, I mostly see "blond" and rarely do I see "blonde" in print.

Comment: @Brian Knoblauch, @Mark Rogers: As a blond, I really don't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm American. My instinct is that if you're talking about sex, the feminine form *blonde* is strongly preferred. Google seems to agree: for phrases like "leggy blonde" and "buxom blonde", the *e* form seems to get about 8x as many hits. (You may want to turn SafeSearch on when you run those, if only because pornographers aren't the world's best spellers.)

Comment: Remind me again why I would want to turn SafeSearch on..?

Comment: " ... if only because pornographers aren't the world's best spellers." I'm not sure what this is supposed to imply (and I'm not checking, since I'm at work). Are you saying that the porn results have a different male/female balance to the non-porn results?

Comment: I wonder why the OED says that "in Britain the form blonde is now preferred in all senses"?

Answer (score 4):

*Blonde/blond* is an example of English retaining a written French gender distinction which is not pronounced in English (though they can be distinguished in oral French).  Another is *fiancée/fiancé* (which also sound the same in French).  So in the following, the spelling is correct even if the sentiment may not be.

> A blonde, a brunette and a redhead
>   walked into a bar.  The barman said,
>   "Is this a joke?"

Comment: This implies that "Three women – a blond, a brunette and a redhead walked into a bar" is wrong in English. It's not.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: as others have said, it seems that *blond woman* is more common in American English than British English, whether deliberately or accidentally.  For some British readers it may be jarring, which is as close as a non-prescriptive language comes to being wrong.

Comment: It's less 'wrong' than 'stairs John the the up to top. stairs of'. And we both know which one is _bound_ to be marked wrong by any teacher. kiamlaluno's answer better represents the actual situation.

Answer (score 2):

About the British usage of the words, I have found the following note, in the *Oxford Dictionary of English 3rd edition*.

> The alternative spellings blonde and blond correspond to the feminine and masculine forms in French, but in English the distinction is not always made, as English does not have such distinctions of grammatical gender. Thus, *blond woman* or *blonde woman*, *blond man* or *blonde man* are all used. The word is more commonly used of women, though, and in the noun the spelling is typically *blonde*. In American usage the usual spelling is *blond* for both adjective and noun.

The NOAD has a note that says what already reported by @Robusto in his answer.

Comment: You should tell us which dictionary, to give them credit.

Comment: My Mac doesn't tell me which dictionary it labels as "British Dictionary." I guess it's OED, as the other dictionary is the NOAD.

Comment: I found out which dictionary it is, looking into the dictionary files.